# Power BI DAX - using monthly totals instead of grand totals

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm having issues with the following calculation:

"Kunden Anzahl" refers to the number of customers via distinct count, with %SG being the percentage. The issue is that Power BI is taking the grand total of 21.801 for the calculation of the percentages instead of the corresponding total of each month (19.337 for 12/2020, 21.391 for 12/2021). This results in the total percentage being less than 100% except for 01/2022.

So what it should do is divide each customer count by the total of its corresponding month - for example 6.326 / 19.337 = 32.7%

I've tried grouping the denominator by month and ignoring the categories by using REMOVEFILTERS but this just replicates the first column.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Reference to comment:
[image]

Data model looks like this - JJJJMM is connected to a date table:
[image]

Comment: From where are your categories coming from? `Druck` and `EDI` and so on? Your data model doesn't seem complete. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Nevermind my first comment - your solution worked! I just had to add some filters I hadn't thought about to the VALUES section of your code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data looks like this

| CustomerID | Category | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | A | 01 January 2021 |
| 21 | A | 01 January 2021 |
| 29 | B | 01 January 2021 |
| 39 | B | 01 January 2021 |
| 6 | B | 01 January 2021 |
| 18 | C | 01 January 2021 |
| 34 | A | 01 February 2021 |
| 29 | A | 01 February 2021 |
| 4 | A | 01 February 2021 |
| 17 | B | 01 February 2021 |
| 24 | B | 01 February 2021 |
| 39 | B | 01 February 2021 |
| 11 | B | 01 February 2021 |
| 1 | B | 01 February 2021 |
| 42 | A | 01 March 2021 |
| 46 | A | 01 March 2021 |
| 2 | A | 01 March 2021 |
| 30 | B | 01 March 2021 |

## DAX Calculation

```
CountDistinct (%) =
VAR CurrentValue =
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[CustomerID] )
VAR AllMonth =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[CustomerID] ),
        ALL ( 'Table' ),
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Month] )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( CurrentValue, AllMonth )
```

## Output

[image]

## Reference

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-allexcept-versus-all-and-values/

Comment: First of all thank you for your help, I think we're getting close. But for some reason I still don't get the correct results, please refer to my edited OP.

Comment: Nevermind my first comment - your solution worked! I just had to add some filters I hadn't thought about to the VALUES section of your code.